# How to find free disk space and analyze disk usage?

Tags: disk-usage

In CentOS and Ubuntu, how do I find out how much free disk space I have left and other disk stats like disk usage?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Type the following command:

`df -h`

- `df`: disk free
- `-h`: makes the output human-readable

Comment: best answer without the need to install additional software!

Comment: df stands for disk filesystem

Answer (score 31):

I covered this pretty extensively in a blog post titled: [Command Line Tools for Analyzing Disk Usage on Fedora/CentOS/RHEL](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/5845/command-line-tools-for-analyzing-disk-usage-on-fedoracentosrhel/#more-5845).

#### [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu)

It’s ncurses based, feature rich and has a nice clean interface and it works from within a shell.

[image: ss of ncdu]

#### [gt5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net/)

- display diskspace used by files & directories within a directory
- display what’s happened since the last ran (see screenshots below)
- optionally provides links to the files, so you can also browse them
- displays entries with their size & the percentage of their parent
- ommits small files/directories
- easy browsing using the cursor-keys
- produces html files for browsing ‘offline’ afterwards

[image: ss of gt5]

#### [Disk Usage Analyzer (aka. Baobab)](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/)

- Single folder scan
- Remote scan
- Monitoring of Home
- Display Data in Treemaps or as Ringschart

[image: ss of baobab]

#### others...

- [xdiskusage](http://xdiskusage.sourceforge.net/)
- [filelight](http://www.methylblue.com/filelight/)
- [fsview](http://lxr.kde.org/source/kde/kde-baseapps/konq-plugins/fsview/README)

In particular fsview is a very nice GUI. I like how it organizes the disk usage visually. It’s actually a KDE application (a plugin to Konqueror) but runs just fine under GNOME. It’s typically part of a package called kdeaddons, and shows up in the Applications menu as “File System Viewer” under Accessories.

[image: ss of fsview]

Comment: Thanks, if anyone comes across additional tools please feel free to drop me a note, I'm always interested in finding other tools in this space!

Comment: @slm, may be you can add `cdu` as well over here. I have mentioned it in the other question's answer. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151684/47538

Comment: Thanks, I thought the konqueror plugin is forever dead, but there you found it!

Comment: @slm blog link is broken

Comment: `k4dirstat` is my preference, thx on the other options!

Comment: @slm is the link to your blog post dead ?

Answer (score 8):

There are a few commands you can use like df, du, and a few more. Just man a few commands to find out how to use them. If you still have a problem finding what you need after that just go to any directory and do this:

```
sudo du --max-depth=1 | sort -nr
```

You'll get something like:

```
2318764 ./usr
777036  ./var
328316  ./lib
222620  ./etc
86136   ./boot
```

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu `dfc` shows a coloured output of your mounted devices and is available via apt:

```
sudo apt-get install dfc
```

output like this:
[image]

Unfortunately this is not available for CentOS as an rpm.

Comment: this Q is asking about CentOS options, dfc is not in any RH repos for either CentOS or Fedora. I already checked this earlier today when I saw your Q showing it 8-). If you google for "dfc rpm" you'll see that no hits show up too. It's just not a popular app on either of these distros, hence my extensive list in my A.

Comment: But he asks"in centos and Ubuntu" but thanks for the hint I edited my answer

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the Ubuntu mention in the body, only the title.