# Alternative command for coloured viewing the size of all files and folders

Tags: file-management

Is there a nice alternative for this? I always use

```
du -shc *
```

to check the size of all files and folders in the current directory. But it would be nice to have a colored and nicely formatted view (for example like `dfc` for viewing the sizes of partitions).

Comment: I see there is a package from here.http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/unix-linux-bsd-pydf-command-in-colours.html

Comment: http://linuxaria.com/article/5-ways-to-check-your-disk-usage-on-linux

Comment: [This](http://gnuwhatimsaying.com/disk-usage-from-dudf-with-colored-graph-output/) might also provide some idea into writing a script to wrap df/du output...

Comment: @Ramesh: your first link to `pydf` is equivalent to `dfc`, which is nice too, but that was not the question

Comment: @rubo77, yeah. That's why I provided the second link which had all the tools. If you had checked that one, it has `ncdu` as well.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73818/in-centos-how-to-find-free-disk-space/73834#73834

Comment: I've been searching for a bit and am not finding anything comparable. If you're desperate I'd think of constructing a filter myself in Bash or or higher level language to colorize the output as desired.

Comment: Console or GUI? Just a full view or something interactive where you can e.g. collapse and expand a subtree?

Comment: console. `gt5` or `ncdu` are already really nice, if they only could be called with less interaction: I don't like that they start a new screen (that you have to leave pressing *q*)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not coloured, but also really nicely ordered by size and visualized:

### ncdu - NCurses Disk Usage

```
apt-get install ncdu
```

> SYNOPSIS
>          ncdu [options] dir
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          ncdu (NCurses Disk Usage) is a curses-based version of the well-known 'du', and provides a fast way to see
>          what directories are using your disk space.

Output looks like this:

```
ncdu 1.10 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                       
--- /var/www/freifunk -------------------------------------------------------------
  470,7MiB [##########] /firmware                                                  
  240,8MiB [#####     ] /ffki-firmware
  157,9MiB [###       ] /gluon-alfred-vis
  102,6MiB [##        ]  chaosradio_162.mp3
  100,2MiB [##        ] /ffki-startseite
   99,6MiB [##        ] /ffki-startseite-origin
   72,3MiB [#         ] /startseite
   66,2MiB [#         ] /metameute-startseite
   35,2MiB [          ] /startseite_site
   11,9MiB [          ] /jungebuehne
```

ncdu is nice, cause you can install it via `apt` on debian. Only colors would be cool and an export function that does not use the whole screen.

### gt5 - a diff-capable 'du-browser'

`gt5` looks quite the same, and there are some colors, but they have no meaning (only all files and folders are green). gt5 is also available via apt:

```
sudo apt-get install gt5
```

Comment: `ncdu` has color output. Run it with `ncdu --color dark`.

Comment: seems like a newer version is needed. ncdu 1.12 has no color option

Comment: confirming ncdu 1.13 has color

Comment: Very loosely related, `dfc` and `pydf` will do something similar for the `df` command (which is what I meant when I accidentally  searched for and came to this result from).

Answer (score 5):

## duf

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muesli/duf/master/duf.png]

### Features

- User-friendly, **colorful** output
- Adjusts to your terminal's width
- Sort the results according to your needs
- Groups & filters devices
- Can conveniently output JSON

### Installation

#### Packages

- Arch Linux: [duf](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/duf/)
- macOS:

  - with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install muesli/homebrew-tap/duf`
  - with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org): `sudo port selfupdate && sudo port install duf`
- Nix: `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.duf`
- [Packages](https://github.com/muesli/duf/releases) in Debian & RPM formats

#### Binaries

- [Binaries](https://github.com/muesli/duf/releases) for Linux, FreeBSD, macOS

Comment: This is a nice alternative for `dfc`but dowsn't show the size of subfolders in a certain directory, like I asked. Or is there a `duf` command, that would do that?

Answer (score 3):

I see the below information from [here](http://arsunik.free.fr/prog/cdu.html).

> cdu (for Color du) is a perl script which call du and display a pretty
>   histogram with optional colors which allow to imediatly see the
>   directories which take disk space.
>
> With no arguments, cdu reports the disk space for all subdirectories
>   of the current directory. With only one directory argument, cdu
>   reports the disk space for all subdirectories of the given directory.
>   You can also call du with no predefined options. For more
>   documentation about available options, see the manpage below.

Answer (score 2):

## [gdu](https://github.com/dundee/gdu)

[image]

tl;dr Similar interface and functionality with `ncdu`, but much faster.

Gdu is a pretty fast disk usage analyzer written in Go. Gdu is intended primarily for SSD disks where it can fully utilize parallel processing. However HDDs work as well, but the performance gain is not so huge.

There are static linked binaries for all major operating systems and packages for ArchLinux, Debian, RedHat/Fedora, Mac OSX (brew) available as well.
See https://github.com/dundee/gdu/releases

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ramesh for the `cdu` link

I've created an oneliner to run `cdu` without installing it:

```bsh
export CDUVER=$(curl -s http://arsunik.free.fr/prog/cdu.html | grep -Po '(?<=cdu-)\d+\.\d+' | head -1); curl -s http://arsunik.free.fr/pkg/cdu-$CDUVER.tar.gz | gunzip | tar x -O cdu-$CDUVER/cdu.pl | perl
```

### Explanation

- `curl -s http://arsunik.free.fr/prog/cdu.html | grep -Po '(?<=cdu-)\d+\.\d+' | head -1`

returns current `cdu` version from the official website

- `export CDUVER=$(curl -s http://arsunik.free.fr/prog/cdu.html | grep -Po '(?<=cdu-)\d+\.\d+' | head -1); curl -s http://arsunik.free.fr/pkg/cdu-$CDUVER.tar.gz | gunzip | tar x -O cdu-$CDUVER/cdu.pl | perl`

declares an actual `cdu` version in `CDUVER` variable

- `curl -s http://arsunik.free.fr/pkg/cdu-$CDUVER.tar.gz`

downloads `tar.gz` package from the official website

- `curl -s http://arsunik.free.fr/pkg/cdu-$CDUVER.tar.gz | gunzip | tar x -O cdu-$CDUVER/cdu.pl`

extracts only `cdu.pl` to `stdout` to send it to `perl`

- `curl -s http://arsunik.free.fr/pkg/cdu-$CDUVER.tar.gz | gunzip | tar x -O cdu-$CDUVER/cdu.pl | perl`

runs extracted script with `perl`